# Correlation coefficient & Coefficient of variation

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

I am not sure what the relationship between correlation coefficient and coefficient of variation. I know that correlation coefficient is r and coefficient of determination is r^2 and CV = s/x-bar but not how to relate them using the information in the problem below.

The correlation coefficient for some data is 0.70. (10 points)
a. Find the coefficient of variation._____
b. What percent of the variation of y can be explained by the variation of x?____

Comment: are you sure about question a.? Question b.; if you know what de coefficient of determination means, you know the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am not sure about part a, part b I got I just forgot to say that above.